# Problems with getClass().getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, eclipse, filepath, bufferedimage, embedded-resource

I am making a project with a graphics environment which uses buffered images from files. I searched and the way I was using (Java.IO file) wouldn't work after exporting the jar, and the way to do it was with `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` but I'm having troubles figuring out filepath

here is my files at eclipse-IDE:
[image: files]

some people said I should move my resources folder inside the src
but I still don't know what would be the text for a image1.png inside of res

I did try searching and implementing but that gave me the errors:

https://pastebin.com/MChSyWH5
here is how the class I'm trying to draw the images is without implementing  getClass().getResourceAsStream() :

```
package src;



import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;







public class Menu {
    
    
    public Rectangle Playbutton = new Rectangle( Game.WIDTH/2-25, 60, 50, 10);
    public Rectangle Exitbutton = new Rectangle( Game.WIDTH/2-25, 80, 50, 10);
    public static String desc = null;
    
    private BufferedImage imagePlay;
    private BufferedImage players1;
    private BufferedImage players2;
    private BufferedImage imageExit;
    private BufferedImage IMPOSSIBLE;
    private BufferedImage Hard;
    private BufferedImage Easy;
    private BufferedImage Normal;
    private BufferedImage imageTitle;
    private BufferedImage imageResume;
    private BufferedImage imageMain;
    private BufferedImage OPTIONS;
    private BufferedImage BACK;
    public static int brightloss = 0;
    public static int stibaum = 0;
    public static boolean sti = true;
    public static boolean showc = false;
    public static enum STATE{
        MAIN,
        P1P2,
        INGAME,
        DIFICULTY, 
        OPTIONS
        
    };
    public static STATE State = STATE.MAIN;
    InputStream input = null;
    public static  STATE Statepre = State;
    public static boolean dark = true;
    public static Slider slider;
    
    public static void SAVESTATE(){
        Statepre = State;
        
        
    }

    public Menu() {
        
     try {
        input = new FileInputStream("res/Playbutt.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
     
         String current;
        try {
            
        current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();
         System.out.println("Current dir:"+current);
          String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                 System.out.println("Current dir using System:" +currentDir);
                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        slider = new Slider(100, 100, 50, false, brightloss);
        
        System.out.println(new File("res/Playbutt.png").getAbsolutePath()+"-arquivo");
        System.out.println(new File("/res/Playbutt.png").exists()+"-arquivo2");
       try { // ImageIO.read(new File("res/Playbutt.png"));              
          imagePlay = ImageIO.read(input);
          IMPOSSIBLE = ImageIO.read(new File("res/IMPOSSIbutt.png"));
          Hard = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Hardbutt.png"));
          Easy = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Easybutt.png"));
          Normal = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Normalbutt.png"));
          players1 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/1P.png"));
         
          players2 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/2P.png"));
          imageExit = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Exitbutt.png"));
          imageTitle = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Title.png"));
          imageResume = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Resumebutt.png"));
          imageMain = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Mainbutt.png"));
          OPTIONS = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Optbutt.png"));
          BACK = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Backbutt.png"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }
    

    
    
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        
        g.setFont(new Font("DefaultFont", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        g.setColor(Colors.Trans_GREEN3);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-10, Game.WIDTH,10);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-9, Game.WIDTH,9);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-8, Game.WIDTH,8);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-7, Game.WIDTH,7);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-6, Game.WIDTH,6);
        g.fillRect(0, Game.HEIGHT-5, Game.WIDTH,5);
        g.setColor(Colors.Trans_GREEN3);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,10);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,9);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,8);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,7);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,6);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH,5);
        g.setColor(Colors.Trans_GREEN3);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 10,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 9,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 8,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 7,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 6,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 5,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Colors.Trans_GREEN3);
        g.setColor(Colors.Trans_GREEN3);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-10, 0, 10,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-9, 0, 9,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-8, 0, 8,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-7, 0, 7,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-6, 0, 6,Game.HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH-5, 0, 5,Game.HEIGHT);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        if(State==STATE.MAIN) {
            
                if(MouseInput.mx>=95 && MouseInput.mx<=145) { 
                     if(MouseInput.my>60&&MouseInput.my<70) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                    g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 59, 54, 14);
                    
                    
                    
                    }
                     else if(MouseInput.my>80&&MouseInput.my<90) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                         g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 79, 54, 14);
                         
                         }
                     else if(MouseInput.my>40&&MouseInput.my<50) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                         g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 39, 54, 14);
                         desc=("");
                         g.setColor(Color.green);
                         g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     }
                }
         g2d.drawImage(this.imageTitle,100,200,null);
         g2d.drawImage(this.OPTIONS, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 60, null);
         g2d.drawImage(this.imagePlay, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 40, null);
         g2d.drawImage(this.imageExit, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 80, null);
         
         double locationX = imageTitle.getWidth() / 2;
         double locationY = imageTitle.getHeight() / 2;
         AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance((Math.toRadians(stibaum)), locationX, locationY);
         AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

            AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
            
            g2d.drawImage(op.filter(imageTitle, null), Game.WIDTH/2-50, 10, null);
            
            g2d.setTransform(old);
            //things you draw after here will not be rotated
         }
        
        else if(State==STATE.INGAME) {
            if(MouseInput.mx>=95 && MouseInput.mx<=145) {
                 if(MouseInput.my>70&&MouseInput.my<80) {
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 69, 54, 14);
                
                }
                 else if(MouseInput.my>90&&MouseInput.my<100) {
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 89, 54, 14);
                     }else if(MouseInput.my>50&&MouseInput.my<60) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                         g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 49, 54, 14);
                         
                     }
                 
            }
            g2d.drawImage(this.imageResume, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 70, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.imageMain, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 50, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.imageExit, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 90, null);
             g2d.drawImage(this.imageTitle, Game.WIDTH/2-50, 10, null);}
        
        else if(State==STATE.P1P2) {
            if(MouseInput.mx>=15 && MouseInput.mx<=40) {
                 if(MouseInput.my>=106&&MouseInput.my<118) { 
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(14, Game.HEIGHT-29, 28, 15);
                     desc=("");
                     g.setColor(Color.green);
                     g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     
                 }}
            if(MouseInput.my>30&&MouseInput.my<90) {
                 if(MouseInput.mx>=60 && MouseInput.mx<=120) {
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-61, 29,66, 66);    
                
                     
        }
                 if(MouseInput.mx>=130 && MouseInput.mx<=190) {
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2+9, 29,66, 66);
                        
                     
        }}
            g2d.drawImage(this.players1, Game.WIDTH/2-60, 30, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.players2, Game.WIDTH/2+10, 30, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.BACK, 15, Game.HEIGHT-28, null);
        }
        else if(State==STATE.DIFICULTY) {
            if(MouseInput.mx>=15 && MouseInput.mx<=40) {
                 if(MouseInput.my>=106&&MouseInput.my<118) { 
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(14, Game.HEIGHT-29, 28, 15);
                     desc=("");
                     g.setColor(Color.green);
                     g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     
                 }}
            if(MouseInput.mx>=95 && MouseInput.mx<=145) {
                 if(MouseInput.my>70&&MouseInput.my<80) {
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 69, 54, 14);
                     g.setColor(Color.green);
                     desc=("for those who want challenge");
                     g.drawString(desc,50 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                
                }
                 else if(MouseInput.my>90&&MouseInput.my<100) {
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 89, 54, 14);
                     desc=("for those who want to cry");
                     g.setColor(Color.green);
                     g.drawString(desc,70 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     }else if(MouseInput.my>50&&MouseInput.my<60) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                         g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 49, 54, 14);
                         desc=("for those who want to play casually");
                         g.setColor(Color.green);
                         g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                         
                         
                     }if(Ball.pmih) {
                      if(MouseInput.my>33&&MouseInput.my<44) {
                         g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                         g.fillRect(Game.WIDTH/2-26, 32, 54, 14);
                         desc=("for those who don't really have a life");
                         g.setColor(Color.green);
                         g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     }}
                 
            }
            if(Ball.pmih) {
            g2d.drawImage(this.IMPOSSIBLE, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 33, null);}
            g2d.drawImage(this.Normal, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 70, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.Easy, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 50, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.Hard, Game.WIDTH/2-25, 90, null);
            g2d.drawImage(this.imageTitle, Game.WIDTH/2-50, 10, null);
             g2d.drawImage(this.BACK, 15, Game.HEIGHT-28, null);
            
            
                
                     
        }
        else if(State==STATE.OPTIONS) {
            if(MouseInput.mx>=15 && MouseInput.mx<=40) {
                 if(MouseInput.my>=106&&MouseInput.my<118) { 
                     g.setColor(Colors.outline);
                     g.fillRect(14, Game.HEIGHT-29, 28, 15);
                     desc=("");
                     g.setColor(Color.green);
                     g.drawString(desc,45 , Game.HEIGHT/2+50);
                     
                 }}
            
            
            
            
            slider.render(g);
             g2d.drawImage(this.imageTitle, Game.WIDTH/2-50, 10, null);
             g2d.drawImage(this.BACK, 15, Game.HEIGHT-28, null);
        
             
        }
        
        
    }




    public void tick() {
        slider.tick();
        if(stibaum<5&&sti==true) {
            stibaum+=1;
        }
        if(stibaum>=5&&sti==true) {sti=false;}
        if(stibaum>-5&&sti==false) {
            stibaum-=1;
        }
        if(stibaum<=-5&&sti==false) {sti=true;}
        if(State==STATE.OPTIONS) {
            Statepre=STATE.MAIN;
        }
        else if(State==STATE.P1P2) {
            Statepre=STATE.MAIN;
        }
        else if(State==STATE.DIFICULTY) {
            Statepre=STATE.P1P2;
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `input = new FileInputStream("res/Playbutt.png");`

This doesn't work. You can't use FIS, you'd have to use `Menu.class.getResource`. Not `getClass()`.

> `ImageIO.read(new File("res/2P.png"));`

Same here.

> ```
> } catch (IOException ex) {
>      // handle exception...
> }
> ```

This isn't how you do this stuff. Get rid of it all, and add `throws IOException` to the constructor. `public static void main` can and generally should be declared to `throws Exception`. You're ignoring the errors, making it harder to debug this problem. Hence, don't do it this way.

None of your code is trying to use `Main.class.getResource`.

`res` is not marked as a source dir in your eclipse project. You need to fix that. You have 2 options:

1. Forget about a `res` dir. Put your images in the exact same place as your java files are. Just move them there - and then `getResource` will work fine. For example, if `img.png` is in the same dir (the exact same dir!) as `Main.java`, then `Main.class.getResource("img.png")` will work fine.
2. Use maven, and then change this project to be a maven based one. Then eclipse will take care of it.

Comment: Can I instead of getting entirely rid of res place it inside of my Java files folder an then use something like Main.class.getResource("res/img.png")?

Comment: Then you'd have to use `"/res/img.png"` (note the leading slash. Without that leading slash you're going from the package the Main.java file is in, and `..` is not legal in these strings).

Comment: i tryed and it worked fine before expoting but after i ran it by cmd and it gave me:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
        at src.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:91) (witch is  imagePlay = ImageIO.read(Menu.class.getResource("Playbutt.png"));)
        at src.Game.<init>(Game.java:100) wich ititializes menu inside game
        at src.Game.main(Game.java:114) wich initializes game

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` returns null if it isn't there, thus, your resource isn't there. I can't debug it for you based on a comment. Use `jar tvf myjar.jar` to check that the image is there, and in the appropriate place. print the result of calling `Main.class.getResource("Main.class")` to systemout to see where this code is looking.